# Can recurring initial payment period be changed after purchase is made?

Tags: 7, commerce

I've installed the drupal commerce framework and the Commerce recurring framework (it's awesome), and i've created a recurring product. That said, someone just made a purchase, and I realized that I accidentally set the initial period as 1 year (and it should be one month). I've since corrected it, but if someone has already purchased the recurring product, how can I change that period? Will it update for existing orders? If not, where can I go to change it for specific orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1935034)

> **Recurring process**
>
> When an order containing a Recurring product is purchased for the
>   first time for the current user, by default the module reacts on
>   "Order is paid in full" event, **a Recurring entity will be created**
>   associated with that product for the current order.
>
> On a cron event, the **recurring entities with past due dates are
>   retrieved** and an order is created for each recurring entity associated
>   with the recurring product and customer.
>
> Note: When this cron event runs it's the time to trigger the payments
>   or use another technique to build a queue of payments.
>
> All this process is driven through Rules so most of it is modifiable

So from reading this, looks like all you gotta do is check the recurring entity that was created for that particular order and see if the due date is 1 month from now or if it's still 1 year from now. If the latter, then edit it and change the due date to 1 month from now.

Comment: I changed the product's initial period to "1 month" yesterday, so the customer should've been charged again today (1 month from the purchase date) but that didn't happen? :/

Comment: I just looked in the report logs, and it looks like it tried to do the recurring order on cron run. The system says "Payment failed (Hard Decline)". That said, is this because the person's card was declined? Or is something wrong with my system? I checked the report logs, and the following errors were thrown upon cron run: "Unable to evaluate action commerce_recurring_provide_order_properties," "Unable to get variable commerce_customer_billing, it is not defined", "Unable to get variable commerce_order, it is not defined,' and a few others. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Brittany The commerce_recurring_ui comes with the recurring module, as shown in the source [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_recurring/tree/). If you're not using it already, I recommend you install [module filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_filter). As far as anonymous users go, I don't know. I've never used this module. There is a rule of thumb to never use modules that have no beta (usually have yellow bg) or not have a stable/full release (have green bg) in the module page. Since you're only using a module that only has a dev release you're taking a lot of risk here.

Comment: So no surprise here that you're getting errors.

Comment: Just double checked, and I do have Recurring UI module installed. Now I'm def not sure why I'm getting the errors.

Comment: Think I just realized the issue. It doesn't look like Moneris API supports Card On File - so Drupal Commerce is trying to run payment for the recurring product, but there's no card on file for the particular user... If you find a work around for this, let me know :/

Comment: @Brittany yeah, card on file only works with [these gateways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Risvj.jpg)